# Unity - Oculus distance grabber won't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Ok Im just trying to implement Oculus's distance grabber setup in Unity, following their sample scene and their one doc link. https://developer.oculus.com/blog/distance-grab-sample-now-available-in-oculus-unity-sample-framework/

The docs are limited to this, and after copying the Distance grab demo script, distance grabbers onto my hand and distance grabbable scripts onto my objects, nothing is working.

I don't understand what the option for sphere cast does, and when it does work (infrequently) it is sporadic and does not "magnetize" the closest object like it should.

What are some possible problems? Setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### maybe this steps might help you or another guys with the same issue.

**1.-** You have to attach a *DistanceGrabbable* script to all the the objects you want to grab in distance, same as in *Grababble* plus distance.

**2.-** Attach *DistanceGrabber* to the object you want to use as a grabber.

**3.-** Set the Grab Objects layer to the layer you want to grab of (You have it in layer 17 atm(?)).

**4.-** The obstruction layer asks you for a layer where you cant grab, maybe is safe to switched to a higher value or -1 perhaps.

**5.-** Add a new game object, add *GrabManager* script to it and an Sphere collider with the radios you want to grab of.

**6.-** Maybe you can move this new game object to your *OVRPlayerController* so you can always grab objects from a certain distance of you (Distance = Collider Radius).

> This implementation will take you 15 min at most, its better a do it
>   yourself way than a demo that often is outdated.